# Clicks but doesn't turn over

Tags: starting

I have a car, but just in the morning times, everything works on it, but all it does is click but won't turn over.

Comment: Battery, solenoid, starter or engine seized... More detail such as make, model, year etc necessary.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You question is too vague for anyone to give you any helpful advice. As Solar Mike has requested, more details about your car, the frequency of the problem and anything you have already attempted would be useful for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always caused by a failing solenoid on the starter. But not all starters have solenoids so others are reluctant to answer because there is not enough info about the vehicle. A bad battery, poor connections, and vehicle specific issues can cause this.

Anything that causes the solenoid to operate, but is not enough to engage the starter contacts will cause this problem. Thus a bad starter might have worn contacts, a poor ground causes reduced voltage to the solenoid, frayed wire has just enough wires to operate the solenoid, but not enough to engage, a bad battery has too low a voltage, a corroded terminal drops the voltage enough. The point is there are too many possibilities without more info - and I didn't even list them all.